# AppleScript to automatically save mail attachments - works for new but not old emails

Tags: applescript, attachment

Thanks everyone for your help so far.  And apologies I asked this in the 'answer' section of a previous question which I now understand I shouldn't have done ..... so I have started a new question here.

SO, I wanted to write a script to save the attachments in emails as they arrive - with a different folder for each email sender.  I got a lot of help from people on this site.

It sort of works ..... for new incoming emails it works perfectly, but when I run it against my old emails in my mailbox it saves some attachments and not others.

I thought the problem was an error on finding a duplicate (which I thought would be unlikely as I have added the time stamp to the filename along with the data stamp of the email.) So I added the delFile delete process to check for a file of the same name and if it finds it to delete it.

When I execute the script it processes a few more attachments than before but not all by any means..... and interestingly nothing get put in the trash bin.

I am now stumped!! As a newcomer to AppleScript I don't know how to debug or handle errors yet.

Can anyone help please?

```
use scripting additions

using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages messageList for rule aRule
        set destinationPath to (POSIX file "/volumes/Data/Dropbox/WORK ITEMS/Email Attachments/") as string
        tell application "Mail"
            repeat with aMessage in messageList
                repeat with anAttachment in mail attachments of aMessage
                    set senderName to (extract name from sender of aMessage)
                    set {year:y, month:m, day:d, hours:h, minutes:min} to date received of aMessage
                    set timeStamp to (d & "/" & (m as integer) & "/" & y & " " & h & "." & min) as string
                    set attachmentName to timeStamp & " - " & name of anAttachment
                    
                    set doSave to true
                    set originalName to name of anAttachment
                    if originalName contains "jpg" then
                        set doSave to false
                    else if originalName contains "jpeg" then
                        set doSave to false
                    else if originalName contains "gif" then
                        set doSave to false
                    else if originalName contains "png" then
                        set doSave to false
                    else if originalName contains "html" then
                        set doSave to false
                    else if originalName contains "ics" then
                        set doSave to false
                    end if
                    
                    if doSave is true then
                        tell application "System Events"
                            if not (exists folder (destinationPath & senderName)) then
                                make new folder at end of alias destinationPath with properties {name:senderName}
                            end if
                        end tell
                    end if
                    
                    if doSave is true then
                        set delFile to destinationPath & senderName & ":" & attachmentName
                        tell application "System Events" to if (exists file delFile) then delete file delFile
                    end if
                    
                    if doSave is true then save anAttachment in file (destinationPath & senderName & ":" & attachmentName) with replacing
                    
                    
                    
                end repeat
            end repeat
        end tell
        
    end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

Thanks

Comment: In your original question I suggested you get rid of the `if` ... `else if` and use a _list_, even gave you the _code_ for it. I also suggested you not use the `/` in the _date_ and use `-` instead. You should listen to those that know more about this than you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I can help with the precise reason for your script's failure, but I might be able to help you see where it's failing.

First of all, I would substitute a list of file extensions that you wish to exclude for the long if...else if block.  Something like:

`set ignore list to  {".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".png", ".html", ".ics"}` at the top of the script, with `set fileExtension to rich text (offset of "." in originalName) thru end of originalName` in the loop.

You can then test:

`if fileExtension is not in ignoreList then`

and wrap this around the saving code (you don't need to do the same test several times).

I think your delete file block is redundant, because it should be doing the same as the following `save...with replacing` (if the file's already there). (You may want to delete the file if it exists, in which case remove the `with replacing` later on.)

To start debugging, first of all remove the code up top that works with incoming messages and replace it with `set messageList to selection`. Try inserting some `display dialog <varname>` in places where you're not sure what's happening. For example, you know what anAttachment is but are you certain what `destinationPath & senderName & ":" & attachmentName` are?

Finally, note that I have NOT run this on YOUR data, so be sure to do a back-up. It shouldn't destroy anything, but better safe than sorry!

Please come back with any questions.  Good luck!

EDIT:

I have added a function at the top (the `on getExtension(fileName)` block. This is called by the line `set fileExtension to my getExtension(originalName)`

This is to refine extension getting by reversing the name string, so that only the first '.' is found. Once got the extension is reversed.

Another crucial part is that this contains `try ... on error ... end try`.  This is how AppleScript does error handling. If there is no '/' an error is thrown. This is caught by `on error` which returns 'skip'. (At this point this is not used in the main program, but could be used to funnel all the output to a catchall folder.)

The final change is that I have wrapped the saving part in `If originalName does not contain "/" then ... end if`. This is to catch those files that contain a '/' and to 'jump over' them without doing anything.

I have NOT needed to add a `delay`, so try without one to start with. It might have been a red herring!

```
set ignoreList to {".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".png", ".html", ".ics"}
set destinationPath to (POSIX file "/volumes/Data/Dropbox/WORK ITEMS/Email Attachments/") as string

on getExtension(fileName)
    try
        set fileName to (reverse of every character of fileName) as string
        set extension to text 1 thru (offset of "." in fileName) of fileName
        set extension to (reverse of every character of extension) as string
        return extension
    on error
        return "skip"
    end try
end getExtension


tell application "Mail"
    set messageList to selection
    
    repeat with aMessage in messageList
        repeat with anAttachment in mail attachments of aMessage
            set senderName to (extract name from sender of aMessage)
            set {year:y, month:m, day:d, hours:h, minutes:min} to date received of aMessage
            set timeStamp to (d & "/" & (m as integer) & "/" & y & " " & h & "." & min) as string
            set attachmentName to timeStamp & " - " & name of anAttachment
            set originalName to name of anAttachment
            if originalName does not contain "/" then
                set fileExtension to my getExtension(originalName)
                if fileExtension is not in ignoreList then
                    
                    tell application "System Events"
                        if not (exists folder (destinationPath & senderName)) then
                            make new folder at end of alias destinationPath with properties {name:senderName}
                        end if
                    end tell
                    
                    save anAttachment in file (destinationPath & senderName & ":" & attachmentName) with replacing
                end if
            end if
        end repeat
    end repeat
    
end tell
```

For calling from a mail rule:

```
use scripting additions

set ignoreList to {".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".png", ".html", ".ics"}
set destinationPath to (POSIX file "/Users/bernardharte/test/") as string

on getExtension(fileName)
    try
        set fileName to (reverse of every character of fileName) as string
        set extension to text 1 thru (offset of "." in fileName) of fileName
        set extension to (reverse of every character of extension) as string
        return extension
    on error
        return "skip"
    end try
end getExtension

using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages messageList for rule aRule
        
        tell application "Mail"
            
            repeat with aMessage in messageList
                repeat with anAttachment in mail attachments of aMessage
                    set senderName to (extract name from sender of aMessage)
                    set {year:y, month:m, day:d, hours:h, minutes:min} to date received of aMessage
                    set timeStamp to (d & "/" & (m as integer) & "/" & y & " " & h & "." & min) as string
                    set attachmentName to timeStamp & " - " & name of anAttachment
                    set originalName to name of anAttachment
                    if originalName does not contain "/" then
                        set fileExtension to my getExtension(originalName)
                        if fileExtension is not in ignoreList then
                            
                            tell application "System Events"
                                if not (exists folder (destinationPath & senderName)) then
                                    make new folder at end of alias destinationPath with properties {name:senderName}
                                end if
                            end tell
                            
                            save anAttachment in file (destinationPath & senderName & ":" & attachmentName) with replacing
                        end if
                    end if
                end repeat
            end repeat
            
        end tell
        
    end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

Comment: Another thought: is `destinationPath` correct? Shouldn't it start with a uppercase 'V'?

Comment: Thank you for the above, very helpful with the explanation and the code.

So....interesting!
I ran it as above with display dialogues with 4 emails and it ran fine.
I added back in the mail commands and ran it for 4 emails and it ran fine
I then removed the display dialogues and ran on 200 emails and it hardly worked at all
BUT when I put the display dialog commands back in it works OK.  is there a chance it is running too fast for mail to keep up sending it mail messages (as the only difference with the display dialogue in is it runs slowly as I need to confirm I have seen the message)

Comment: You could slow things up by inserting `delay 10` [seconds] (on the line) after the attachment save. If that makes a difference, try reducing it to the smallest that helps.

Comment: OK so what have I learned....

Some attachments don't have anything after the "." so the file extension in the script above caused an error that stopped the script - my original script may well have thrown the same error

So tried script removing the code to not save jpgs etc....

I now get a script error - mail got an error: AppleEvent handler Failed - but after a lot more attachments have been saved

Any idea what this is ?

Slowing down definately helps

Comment: That seems likely. First question: what do you want to do with those attachments without extensions?

Comment: OK - this happens when it comes across an attachment with a "/" in the filename.....

Comment: What line is highlighted when you get that failure?

Comment: I am happy to ignore attachments without extensions if there's a way to do that.  Also need to skip the save command if the filename contains a "/"

Any thoughts?

Thank you Lorccan for your help with this

Comment: save anAttachment in file (destinationPath & senderName & ":" & attachmentName) with replacing

Is highlighted when I get the error

Comment: I'll edit the code in the original answer and explain what I've done.

Comment: Now getting used to debugging a little.

Wont affect your code too much but what I can see is the original attachment contains a / (rebus/price) but when I get the script to display attachmentName it has become a ":" (so display dialog shows rebus:price)

Comment: That explains why the problem arises:  the colon is used as a path delimiter on macOS. I'm honestly not sure how it gets transposed from one to another, but you could handle it by substituting something else at that position in the name string. Probably for another time ;)

Comment: Works a treat stand alone - but I am having trouble putting it into the script that works when the rile calls for it .... there's obviously an order to the script which I can't seem to get right?

Comment: Sorry. Been away for a while. I'm in a hurry now, but will check back tomorrow. I'll edit script above to show where I would put the parts that work with the mail rule. Do let me know if you get it working.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've added this in and the edits to make it run on the rule don't seem to work - I had the same problem last night it just gets stuck early in the script. 
I changed the desintationPath and also tried with "set messageList to selection" in the script and also deleted  (I don't think this is needed when it runs from a rule) but in both cases it doesn't save the attachment when called from a rule.

Comment: You're eight about `set messageList to selection`  I overlooked that in my haste.  I'll have a look at the main issue and come back to you.

Comment: I can't determine reason it's not running as a mail rule. I suspect it's something to do with permissions/sandboxing. I suggest you post another question specifically about that - along with your script. You'll get more help that way.